# Making Bitcoins faster with friends?

Tags: mining-pools

I was wondering whether me and a friend (both with powerful graphic cards), would be able to choose to work on the same block, therefore solving it faster and theoretically earning bitcoins faster? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Point is that you will earn twice of 0.

Graphics cards are too slow by now by a factor of around 1000 - mining is done using specialized chips these days. And twice "awfully terribly ridiculously slow" is STILL "awfully terribly ridiculously slow".